# TCL Freeing up memory

Tags: tcl

I have a basic question regarding memory management in TCL.

1. Suppose I have a Tcl procedure. Inside the procedure I declare an array and add some data in it. I do some number crunching on that array. My question is before the procedure returns do I need to manually delete the array? Using:

   ```
   unset <array_name>
   ```

   My answer is no. But I am not sure since I don't know if there is a garbage collector in Tcl. Can anyone comment on this please.
2. Is using array in Tcl bad? I want to create Array of lists and while reading discussions on stack overflow people told to use dict for these kind of stuff but since I have Tcl 8.4 I can't. What is the problem with arrays in Tcl?

Comment: may be arrays and not bad just more cumbersome if going for multi dimensions than dict. However, I do not have anything that compares memory management of the two techniques. Which one is more efficient etc?

Comment: If you do 'number crunching' some other data structure can sometimes be better (BLT vectors or something from the NAP http://wiki.tcl.tk/4015 package for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Suppose I have a Tcl procedure. Inside the procedure I declare an array and add some data in it. I do some number crunching on that array. My question is before the procedure returns do I need to manually delete the array?

No. It will be deleted when the procedure returns (i.e., its lifespan is bounded to that of the stack frame). You may `unset` it earlier if you wish, which will free up its memory then, but you don't *need* to do that.

> 1. Is using array in Tcl bad? I want to create Array of lists and while reading discussions on stack overflow people told to use dict for these kind of stuff but since I have Tcl 8.4 I can't. What is the problem with arrays in Tcl?

Arrays are absolutely fine in 8.4, so long as you remember that they are a collection that implements a map from arbitrary string keys to variables. Dicts are for cases where you want a *value* that holds a map from strings to arbitrary values. (There's a dict extension for 8.4 somewhere about.) You can use arrays to model matrices by choosing some character as a separator between the sub-indices (e.g., a comma) and this technique has been used by many people to great effect.

*However* it is more efficient to model them as lists of lists; the `lset` and multi-index `lindex` permit efficient update and lookup of elements of the resulting matrix. (It is a bit verbose though.) If you're dealing with a lot of data, the improved efficiency can be very useful. (Sparse matrices may be better done as a Tcl array despite that.) Also note that if you can upgrade to 8.5, a number of operations there are significantly faster (notably including testing for the presence of an element of an array with `info exists`).

Comment: Lists of list is fine but number of steps to fetch data will also increase. For example I have a list like this: `{1 2 3 4} {5 6 7 8}` then to access `2` I have to use lindex twice. correct? `set var [lindex $mlist 0]` will give me `{1 2 3 4}` then second `set var2 [lindex $var 1]` will give me `2`.

Comment: You can do it like that, or you can use the multi-index form of `lindex`: `set var2 [lindex $mlist 0 1]`. The `lset` command also takes multiple indices if desired, and both `lset` and `lindex` can take a list of indices as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Tcl does have garbage collection (the exact implementation is undefined, whether it's reference counting or some other method). So no, you don't have to use `unset` to avoid memory leaks.

I'm not sure why arrays would be considered bad. You will have to provide references to such discussions to get specific comments.

Comment: This is one discussion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323585/how-do-i-create-and-iterate-through-a-hash-of-hashes-in-tcl

Comment: may be arrays and not bad just more cumbersome if going for multi dimensions than dict. However, I do not have anything that compares memory management of the two techniques. Which one is more efficient etc?

Comment: I don't think people normally worry about efficiency too much when programming in Tcl. If you're using Tcl 8.4, there's no problem using arrays.

Comment: You only have to unset things that are of limited lifespan in a persistent context (e.g., in the global namespace), but some things (e.g., file handles, http tokens, objects) need manual deletion under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to free your local vars when you exit a procedure.  They are automatically freed.  This is the case most of the time, but there are exceptions (some extensions may require you to free things explicitly, and some packages, notably http, create tokens that need to be cleaned up)

If you create large arrays in the global namespace, these will not be freed, because they can still be accessed.

There is no problem using arrays in tcl, but make sure you are using the right tool. In tcl an array is an "associative array", that is it is indexed by string.  If you need a c-style array indexed by integer a plain old list may be better (you can pass it around by value) but you might consider it a little clumsier (subscripting is a command rather than a variable reference with a subkey)

Comment: Subscripting of lists _is_ very fast, much faster than indexing into arrays (or dictionaries).